# How do you get a different value for a label each time a button is pressed in `tkinter`?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, command

So I'm making a random name generator. Everything is pretty much finished in my GUI. The problem is I can only press my generate button once to get all the values that are needed. How can I press the button infinite amount of times, getting different values each time the button is pressed.

Do I need to make a loop of some sort? I put a `lambda` in there. That holds back the values from just showing on my screen as soon as you open the GUI. This way you can press the button and text appears like normal.

```
firstnameli = ['Chris ', 'Kevin ', 'Jeff ', 'Marty ', 'Dolen ']
lastnameli = ['Smith', 'Miller', 'Jones', 'Davis', 'Brown']

full_name = random.choice(firstnameli) + random.choice(lastnameli)

#this allows text to be put in the text box
estr = StringVar()
estr.set(full_name)

fullnameentry = Entry(MyWin, borderwidth=5, font=("Helvetica", 15))

def buttonfunc():
    fullnameentry.config(text=estr)

genbutton = Button(MyWin, text="GENERATE", activebackground="blue", command= lambda: buttonfunc())
```

Comment: @Jayjayyy thanks for letting me know. I have one more question. Is there anyway you can explain how using    .tk   puts the text in the Entry box?  The way I imported tkinter was     from tkinter import * . Does that have anything to do with it? (Please forgive. I dont know how to use code tags.)

Comment: @Jayjayyy i used `from tkinter import *` So does it matter how I import tkinter?. I am aware that `*` means everything. So it wouldn't only make sense to import evrything from the `tkinter` package?

Comment: @Jayjayyy Ok thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generate the random name only once. From then on `estr` is always going to be the same value.

If you're comfortable with `lambda` you can use that to make `full_name` into a function:

```
full_name = lambda: random.choice(firstnameli) + random.choice(lastnameli)
```

Afterwards, you'll have to *call* `full_name` since it's not a simple string variable anymore but a function:

```
estr.set(full_name())
```

Also, you seem to miss setting `textvariable=estr` for `fullnameentry`.

Everything put together:

```
firstnameli = ['Chris ', 'Kevin ', 'Jeff ', 'Marty ', 'Dolen ']
lastnameli = ['Smith', 'Miller', 'Jones', 'Davis', 'Brown']

full_name = lambda: random.choice(firstnameli) + random.choice(lastnameli)

#this allows text to be put in the text box
estr = StringVar()
estr.set(full_name())

fullnameentry = Entry(MyWin, textvariable=estr, borderwidth=5, font=("Helvetica", 15))

def buttonfunc():
    estr.set(full_name())

genbutton = Button(MyWin, text="GENERATE", activebackground="blue", command=buttonfunc)
```

---

I also think your code might be a little bit too complicated at some points. Here is a minimal and complete `tkinter` example, maybe this will help you in some way:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def random_name():
    first_names = ['Chris', 'Kevin', 'Jeff', 'Marty', 'Dolen']
    last_names = ['Smith', 'Miller', 'Jones', 'Davis', 'Brown']
    full_name = '{} {}'.format(random.choice(first_names), random.choice(last_names))
    return full_name

def update_label_and_entry():
    new_random_name = random_name()
    label.config(text=new_random_name)
    entry.delete(0, tk.END) # delete content from 0 to end
    entry.insert(0, new_random_name) # insert new_random_name at position 0

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text="New random name", command=update_label_and_entry)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Of course, this code is not perfect. The code could be improved further for example by moving `first_names` and `last_names` to a global namespace, so other methods can access the values, too. Also, you could write a class for your window or for the label which will include the `update_label` method.

Comment: I think you should store the list outside of the function in the global namespace.

Comment: Yes. The reason I think its best that those list are outside of the function is so they can be accessed by any code that might need them later in development. For updating names or other random generators. From a ease of use standpoint I usually place list like these in the global.

Comment: Yes I do agree that a class is the best solution as to avoid the global namespace being one of the biggest advantages. In any case. Thanks for adding that info into your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. Your code is way more organized. But it still isn't working. I still need to use a lambda expression on the button command so the text doesn't show when I open my GUI. I still can't press the button an infinte number of times. Only once.

Comment: @Jayjayy Yes, that is exactly what I want. Hence, the generate button. If I dont put a lambda expression on the button command like in my first example, the text just sits there. The button has no function at all.  Pretty much nothing happens

Comment: I think the first example in this answer just makes things more confusing, and doesn't solve the problem being asked. The second example is good, however.

Comment: @Jayjayy I tested your code out and it works perfectly. I just don't understand why my code won't work? Would you like to take a look at it. You might be a little freaked out by it but I organized as best as I can

Comment: @Jayjayy Ok I know what wrong with my code. I want to put the text in an Entry box. NOT A LABEL.  The reason for this is so people can copy and paste it. In my first example estr is what can make that happen. So something must be going wrong there.

Comment: @Jayjayy Ok thank you. What line are you referring to? Can you also explain lines 13 and 14?